# iOS: After changing renderbuffer glCheckFramebufferStatus returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_OES

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, render

I'm making a painting application.
I'd like to change sustain to add redo and undo functions.
But I can't make a complete framebuffer after render something.

```
CAEAGLLayer* pGLLayer = ( CAEAGLLayer* )self.layer;
pGLLayer.opaque = YES;
pGLLayer.drawableProperties = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[ NSNumber numberWithBool:YES ],
                                                                 kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                                                 kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8,
                                                                 kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                                                                                                                     nil ];     
mpGLContext = [ [EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1 ];
[ EAGLContext setCurrentContext:mpGLContext ];
glGenFramebuffers( 1, &FrameBuffer );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer );   
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &firstColorBuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, firstColorBuffer );
[ mpGLContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:( CAEAGLLayer* )self.layer ];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, firstColorBuffer );
glOrthof( 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f );
glViewport( 0, 0, 320, 480 );

    // here status is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );

/** render function  **/
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &secondColorBuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, secondColorBuffer );
[ mpGLContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:( CAEAGLLayer* )self.layer ];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, firstColorBuffer );

// here status is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_OES
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
```

glCheckFramebufferStatus returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_OES.
But I bind renderbuffer.
So there is an attachment for the framebuffer.
What should I fix in this code to make a complete framebuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the call after `/** render function  **/`

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, firstColorBuffer );
```

with

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, secondColorBuffer );
```

You are attaching `firstColorBuffer` twice and according to the [docummentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferRenderbuffer.xml) end up with a broken attachment:

> Any previous attachment to the *attachment* logical buffer of the
>   currently bound framebuffer object is broken.

Comment: Sorry,I mistyped a code.
I correct it.But glCheckFramebufferStatus still returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_OES.